# How to check function error using if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, net-snmp

I am creating session and sending traps to snmp devices, my code is working as expected and sending trap messages to host, Now below i have added validation to check if session has error while establishing connection, then throw error dont send trap message. So my question here is how can we execute function while checking if/esle condition and see if error exist in `validateSession` if error exist close session else send trap.

main.js

```
 var session = snmp.createSession(host,"public",sessionOptions);

 try {
        function validateSession(){
            session.on ("error", function (error) {
                console.log (error);
                session.close ();
            });
        };
        if(!validateSession(){
            session.trap(trapOid, varbinds, options, function (error) {
             if (error)
             console.log(error);
             else
             console.log('SNMP successfully delivered');
             });
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("SNMP processing error: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: `if(!validateSession(){`…`})` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `validateSession` doesn't return anything. Also, it's asynchronous so you aren't going to catch the session errors in your `try-catch`.

Comment: i want to see what would be right approach in above case new to Javascript if i can get example it would be very helpful.